# Woocommerce V 3.3.3 not sending email when product is going out of stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, notifications

The Woocommerce not sending emails when product is out of stock or lowstock notification to the admin. But if an new order received then the email's are received in admin email. Have configured everything correctly. I have attached screenshot of my configuration.

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kLMr.jpg)